# How to get azure AccessToken from client certificate in C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I used below code to get Azure access token for my Service Principal which has secret.

```html
public static async Task<string> GetAzAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
{
    string authContextURL = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/";
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
    var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }
    string token = result.AccessToken;

    return token;
}
```

Can someone give me sample method to get Azure access token for my pme account (myalias@pme.gbl.msidentity.com) using client certificate.(like a login prompt or something)